# Auto Increment number on SuiteCRM Accounts

Tags: suitecrm

I tried several answers from suitecrm forum And here. And I can't implement them to the present version of Suite CRM.

Here is the one I tried last and stuck for further clarification.

add a new file in custom/Extension/modules/yourmodule/Ext/Vardefs e.g. autoincrement.php with the following :

```
<?php
  $dictionary['YOUR_MODULE']['fields']['NAME_OF_AUTO_INC_FIELD'] =  array(
        'name' => 'NAME_OF_AUTO_INC_FIELD',
        'vname' => 'LBL_LABEL_OF_AUTO_INC_FIELD',
        'type' => 'int',
        'readonly' => true,
        'len' => 11,
        'auto_increment' => true,
       'disable_num_format' => true,
    );
?>
```

and also add unique index for the field in that file

```
<?php
 $dictionary['YOUR_MODULE']['indices']['NAME_FOR_INDEX'] = array(
        'name' => 'NAME_FOR_INDEX',
        'type' => 'unique',
        'fields' => array('NAME_OF_AUTO_INC_FIELD'),
    );
?>
```

Run a Quick Rebuild and Repair in Admin -> Repair and execute the changes.

after that it shows an empty text box. There it iterates automatically, when new account saved. But I want to show the next auto increment number here in this Accounts page itself.

Instead of default value, I want to show the next auto value in the new Account form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't out the box behaviour - you'll need to add some customisations to do this.

I would create a new vardef `auto_inc_preview` which is a function type field. This can then be used to grab the largest number from the DB and display this + 1.

A possible issue with this would be that the number a user sees may not be the id that gets generated - for example if two or more people create an account at the same time.